# Is $\operatorname{Fib}(B)$ cartesian closed when $B$ is?

Tags: category-theory, fibration

Is the ($2$-)category $\operatorname{Fib}(B)$ of fibrations over $B$ cartesian closed whenever $B$ is?

If not, are there some restrictions that would make it so? For example, consider restricting to it discrete fibrations.

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? :)

Comment: Products should work pointwise, i.e. take the product category of the total spaces and make it fibered over products in B. Exponentials are less obvious.